# Null value from SQL datareader not evaluating as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, null, converters, dbnull

Read a lot about null, `DBNull` and so forth and feel like I get the concepts, but clearly I'm not.

I'm querying a SQL Server database table and have a column that allows null.

I'm putting the query results in a dataset and I can clearly see that the value for row in question appears to be `NULL` but it just looks "blank" in the DataSet Visualizer. The column is definitely `NULL` in the SQL Server table for the row in question, and my select query is a direct select statement (i.e. no `isnull` code is used in my SQL).

I've tried to work around this seemingly simple issue but my test for nulls keeps treating the value as not being null. However my code skips to the else section and tries to convert the value in the `pct cancelled` column and keeps giving me an error with the `Convert.ToDouble`

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

I've tried playing around with the datatypes on the `_cancelledPct` column but nothing seems to help. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious but can't figure out why this value that I'm 99.9999% sure is null isn't evaluating as such in my `System.DBNull.Value` section (note I've also tried `dr["pct cancelled"] == null` and had similar results).

```
if (dr["pct cancelled"] != System.DBNull.Value)                    
    this._cancelledPct = 0; 
else
    this._cancelledPct = Convert.ToDouble(dr["pct cancelled"]);
```

UPDATE:

This is how my data reader and data row are setup:

```
DataRow dr = dimCampaignSplitRow;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = _etlTask.Job.CrsConnection;
cmd.CommandTimeout = 1800;
SqlDataReader theDr = null;
SqlDataAdapter da = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your condition is flipped.

```
//Changed from != to ==
if (dr["pct cancelled"] == System.DBNull.Value)                    
    //If it is null, 0
    this._cancelledPct = 0; 
else
    //If not, convert
    this._cancelledPct = Convert.ToDouble(dr["pct cancelled"]);
```

Comment: Thanks mlorbetske, I think you're right.  However after fixing that I still get the same "Object cannot be cast..." error.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the `SqlDataReader` by calling the `.IsDBNull()` method like this:

```
if (dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("pct cancelled"))
   this._cancelledPct = 0; 
else
   this._cancelledPct = Convert.ToDouble(dr["pct cancelled"]);
```

Comment: marc_s, I'm usoing C# in VS2008 and isDBNull doesn't seem to exist (I do get IsNull as an option) and GetOrdinal doesn't show as valid either.  Are you using C# s well, or could it be that my data reader is setup differently from the way I should.

Comment: @RyanWard: ah - sorry - you have `dr` but it's not the `SqlDataReader` (as I suspected from the naming) but the `DataRow` - the `.IsDBNull()` method exists on the `SqlDataReader` - so `theDr.IsDBNull(....)` should work

Comment: marc_s, just figured out how misleading my code was (in 99% of my other code dr is for the datareader so I really even confused myself).  Posted an answer above, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Actually thanks to both marc_s and mlorbetske for putting me on the right track.  In hindsight I think I just needed a good night's sleeping.  Fixing my code per mlorbetske's post and then in looking into marc_s's advice, I came up with this, which works.  I simply needed to do a Convert.IsDBNull on the field in question.

There's 2 hours of a Tuesday night I'll never get back lol.  Thanks again.

```
if (Convert.IsDBNull(dr["pct cancelled"]))
    this._cancelledPct = 0;  
else
    this._cancelledPct = Convert.ToDouble(dr["pct cancelled"]);
```